# Raspberry Pi DPI Colour issues

Tags: lcd, raspberry-pi-os

I have a DPI screen with an interface, I have setup DPI on the pi following this guide: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/dpi/README.md

I am getting an image but the colours are off. In fact it looks like no Blue and green is displaying as yellow

[image]
Actually, if I swap B and R in the magic number, then Blue displays as Blue and Red is missing.  I think this is better even though it is using the wrong colour order but it seems that red is missing and green is still yellow

[image]

Any ideas on where to start with troubleshooting?  It's a bit strange that an entire colour can be missing.

These are my settings

```
dtoverlay=dpi18
#overscan_left=0
#overscan_right=0
#overscan_top=0
#overscan_bottom=0
#framebuffer_width=800
#framebuffer_height=480
enable_dpi_lcd=1
display_default_lcd=1
dpi_group=2
dpi_mode=87
dpi_output_format=0x7f226
dpi_timings=720 0 15 15 15 720 0 10 10 10 0 0 0 60 0 35113500 6
```

Comment: Photographer in me says ‘check the cabling’ as a colour is missing - You May want to edit the question and provide links to the actual board.

Comment: The board is one I designed and had made.  I have two of them fully assembled and get the same results on both of them.  I've just double checked with a multi-meter between the FPC connector and the IDC header and all the red pins are going where they should point to point

Comment: Possible clash between the magic number and the overlay?  As the overlay controls the pin mode maybe this is not being set correctly for you?

Comment: Thanks, that got me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that as mentioned in [this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=240256) (and initially suggested by Andyroo), dtoverlay=dpi18 doesn't actually set the pins up, so the following needs adding to config.txt for mode 6

```
gpio=0-9=a2
gpio=12-17=a2
gpio=20-25=a2
```